# libvlc and qt issue

Tags: qt, libvlc

I am trying to use libvlc on windows 7 for playback in Qt Widget. I need some of the functionality provided by libvlc not present in phonon. I am using the below code :

```
_videoWidget = new QFrame(this);
qDebug()<<fileName;
const char * const vlc_args[] = {
    "-I qt4",
              "--extraintf=logger",
              "--verbose=2" };
 _vlcinstance = libvlc_new(sizeof(vlc_args) / sizeof(vlc_args[0]), vlc_args);
 _mp = libvlc_media_player_new (_vlcinstance);
 _m = libvlc_media_new_path(_vlcinstance, fileName.toAscii());
 libvlc_media_player_set_media (_mp, _m);
 libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd(_mp, 0);//(_videoWidget->winId());
 int windid = reinterpret_cast<int>(_videoWidget->winId());
 libvlc_media_player_set_xwindow (_mp, windid );
 libvlc_media_player_play (_mp);
```

After I select the file to play it just does nothing, no frames no debugging output ?
The debug console op is :

```
    [0ac8f670] main libvlc debug: VLC media player - 2.0.3 Twoflower
[0ac8f670] main libvlc debug: Copyright © 1996-2012 VLC authors and VideoLAN
[0ac8f670] main libvlc debug: revision 2.0.3-0-g77aa89e
[0ac8f670] main libvlc debug: configured with ../extras/package/win32/../../../configure  '--enable-update-check' '--enable-lua' '--enable-faad' '--enable-flac' '--enable-theora' '--enable-twolame' '--enable-quicktime' '--enable-avcodec' '--enable-merge-ffmpeg' '--enable-dca' '--enable-mpc' '--enable-libass' '--enable-x264' '--enable-schroedinger' '--enable-realrtsp' '--enable-live555' '--enable-dvdread' '--enable-shout' '--enable-goom' '--enable-caca' '--disable-portaudio' '--disable-sdl' '--enable-qt4' '--enable-skins2' '--enable-sse' '--enable-mmx' '--enable-libcddb' '--enable-zvbi' '--disable-telx' '--enable-sqlite' '--disable-dirac' '--host=i586-mingw32msvc' '--enable-crystalhd' 'host_alias=i586-mingw32msvc'
[0ac8f670] main libvlc debug: searching plug-in modules
[0ac8f670] main libvlc debug: loading plugins cache file E:\Work\Local_WorkingCopy\VidTest\plugins\plugins.dat
[0ac8f670] main libvlc debug: recursively browsing `E:\Work\Local_WorkingCopy\VidTest\plugins'
[0ac8f670] main libvlc debug: saving plugins cache E:\Work\Local_WorkingCopy\VidTest\plugins\plugins.dat
[0ac8f670] main libvlc debug: plug-ins loaded: 388 modules
[0ac8f670] main libvlc debug: translation test: code is "C"
[0ac8f670] main libvlc debug: CPU has capabilities MMX MMXEXT SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 FPU 
[0ac8f670] main libvlc debug: looking for memcpy module: 4 candidates
[0ac8f670] main libvlc debug: using memcpy module "memcpymmxext"
[0c680ab8] main interface debug: looking for interface module: 1 candidate
```

Can someone point out the mistake in this code ?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work without 
`libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd` and `libvlc_media_player_set_xwindow`

Libvlc generates a window automatically if you dont make the manual calles. Thats how you can figure out if its a libvlc problem.

Bye Darian

Answer (score 0):

This my code sample which works fine:

```
const char *const vlc_args [] = {
        "--verbose=3"   //be much more verbose then normal for debugging purpose
        ,"--quiet"
    };

    instance         = libvlc_new (sizeof(vlc_args) / sizeof(vlc_args[0]), vlc_args);
    player           = libvlc_media_player_new (instance);
    ...

    libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd (player, reinterpret_cast<HWND> (winId));
    QByteArray temp  = url.toEncoded ();
    const char *path = temp.constData ();
    media            = libvlc_media_new_location (instance, path);
    libvlc_media_player_set_media (player, media);
    int res          = libvlc_media_player_play (player);
```